# Automatically submit after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript

In javascript, how can I automatically submit after 10 seconds after loading the page? This is the input type:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: Please do some basic research before asking for help. You could at least google "how to submit a form" which would lead you [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit), and "how to delay an action" which would lead you [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). See [how much effort is expected from Stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a submit button if you want to submit it automatically, You can use the following code:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("FORMID").submit();
}, 10000)
```

Of course instead of `getElementById` you can use query selector which selects the form.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the .click method of the button after 10s:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector("input[type='submit']").click();
}, 10000)
```

Comment: can I set the input submit to hidden?

Comment: Yes you can: `document.querySelector("input[type='submit']").setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;")`